# Making wxStyledTextCtrl use exact same font as wxTextCtrl

Tags: c++, fonts, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl, wxstyledtextctrl

my problem is best described by the image below:

[image: different fonts]

The two text edit controls on the left are wxTextCtrl and the one one the far right is wxStyledTextCtrl. I'm using wxStyledTextCtrl for the disassembly editor (the one on the right) because I want to enable syntax highlighting for it.

I'm using the exact same font for all of these controls yet the Scintilla editor always seems to differ in font style/line height.

```
wxFont font = wxFont(11, wxFontFamily::wxFONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wxFontStyle::wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, 90, false, wxEmptyString);
```

Is there any way I can ensure that all of these controls use exactly the same font?